# Using BERT Embeddings in Keras Embedding layer

Tags: python-3.x, keras, nlp, embedding, bert-language-model

I want to use the BERT Word Vector Embeddings in the Embeddings layer of LSTM instead of the usual default embedding layer. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55669695/how-to-feed-bert-embeddings-to-lstm) answer your question?

Comment: It will work if I have word embeddings from a single sentence. What if I have embedding matrix made out of several sentences?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you're trying to do with the network, I guess.

Comment: Excuse me did you solve it please

Comment: @user1 you may refer this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/62466528/10097229

Comment: Thanks for replying. Excuse me ,Did you get word embedding then apply it in the weight of this line . `Embedding=(vocab_size,output=..)`

Comment: @user1 yes got embeddings first

Answer (score 3):

Hope these links are of help:

- Huggingface transformers with Tf2.0 (TPU training) with embeddings: (https://www.kaggle.com/abhilash1910/nlp-workshop-2-ml-india)
- Contextual Similarity with BERT Embeddings(Pytorch):
  https://github.com/abhilash1910/BERTSimilarity
- For generating unique sentence embeddings using BERT/BERT variants, it is recommended to select the correct layers. In some cases the following pattern can be taken into consideration for determining the embeddings(TF 2.0/Keras):

```py
transformer_model = transformers.TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-large-uncased')

input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,), name='input_token', dtype='int32')
input_masks_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,), name='masked_token', dtype='int32')
X = transformer_model(input_ids, input_masks_ids)[0]
X = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(X)
X = tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ids, input_masks_ids], outputs = X)(X)
```

- If this does not work, then please refer to "Feature Extraction " in the huggingface repository to get embeddings.(https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html)
  A sample is provided:

```py
import numpy as np
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, pipeline, TFDistilBertModel
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
def transformer_embedding(name,inp,model_name):

    model = model_name.from_pretrained(name)
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(name)
    pipe = pipeline('feature-extraction', model=model, 
                tokenizer=tokenizer)
    features = pipe(inp)
    features = np.squeeze(features)
    return features
z=['The brown fox jumped over the dog','The ship sank in the Atlantic Ocean']
embedding_features1=transformer_embedding('distilbert-base-uncased',z[0],TFDistilBertModel)
embedding_features2=transformer_embedding('distilbert-base-uncased',z[1],TFDistilBertModel)
distance=1-cosine(embedding_features1[0],embedding_features2[0])
print(distance)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you miss part of the code in the second snippet. Could you complete it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Updated the second snippet.

Comment: If I am using your second snippet or sentence-transformer to generate bert embedding, how it should apply in keras model? What I have in my mind is to give a input like (number_of_instance, dimensions)   Ex-: (2000,768) as a numpy array